# actionscript 3 creating an object with changing numbers at the end

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I create objects with the same base name such as employe but change the number at the end? I have the first 3 employees created but I'd like to be able to create other objects with employe but with different numbers at the end. Is that possible? If so would there be any good reason to do it? Or would it be better to just add the objects into the array without naming it?

This is my code.

```
package  {

    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;

    public class U2TF5_Employes extends MovieClip{

        //Crée les premier 3 employes
        var employe1: Object = new Object();
        var employe2: Object = new Object();
        var employe3: Object = new Object();

        //Crée le tableay principal et un tableau avec les propriétés
        var employees: Array = new Array();
        var proprietes: Array = ["numero", "prenom", "nomDeFamille", "salaireAnnuel", "dateEmbauche"];

        //Constructor code
        public function U2TF5_Employes() {
            btnAjouter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ajouter);
            btnAfficher.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, afficher);
            btnSupprimer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, supprimer);

            employe1 = {numero: 1, prenom: "Paul", nomDeFamille: "Breau", salaireAnnuel: 0.1, dateEmbauche: "16/02/29"};
            employe2 = {numero: 2, prenom: "William", nomDeFamille: "Tam", salaireAnnuel: 10000000, dateEmbauche: "16/02/28"};
            employe3 = {numero: 3, prenom: "Erica", nomDeFamille: "Bélanger", salaireAnnuel: 999999999, dateEmbauche: "05/09/12"}; 

            employees.push(employe1);
            employees.push(employe2);
            employees.push(employe3);
        }

        private function ajouter(e: MouseEvent): void {
        }

        private function afficher(e: MouseEvent): void {
            txtEmployes.text = "";
            for (var i: int = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
                for each (var proprietesEmploye: String in proprietes) {
                    txtEmployes.appendText(proprietesEmploye + ": " + employees[i][proprietesEmploye] + "\n");
                }
                txtEmployes.appendText("\n");
            }
        }

        private function supprimer(e: MouseEvent): void {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Any **DisplayObject** has a **name** property, you can assign one to get this object with **getChildByName(...)** method from the **DisplayObject**'s parent. Or you can have an **Array** of these instances. Or you can devise an associative array (a.k.a hash **Object**) and store the links to these instances you create by some **String** keys, which (by pure coincidence) could be "empoyee1", "empoyee2", and so on. None of these are good or bad. Pick one you understand better or one that works better for you or for given case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very possible to create more objects.  One possibility is to update your class like this:

```
public class U2TF5_Employes extends MovieClip{

    //Crée les premier 3 employes
    var employe4: Object = new Object();

    //Constructor code
    public function U2TF5_Employes() {
        //Add these lines to the end of the existing function
        employe4 = {numero: 4, prenom: "Erica", nomDeFamille: "Bélanger", salaireAnnuel: 999999999, dateEmbauche: "05/09/12"}; 

        employees.push(employe4);
    }
}
```

Another option is to declare your additional objects and push them:

```
    public function U2TF5_Employes() {
        //Add these lines to the end of the existing function
        var employeToAdd = {numero: 5, prenom: "Erica", nomDeFamille: "Bélanger", salaireAnnuel: 999999999, dateEmbauche: "05/09/12"}; 
        employees.push(employeToAdd);

        employeToAdd = {numero: 6, prenom: "Erica", nomDeFamille: "Bélanger", salaireAnnuel: 999999999, dateEmbauche: "05/09/12"}; 
        employees.push(employeToAdd);
        //etc

        //or even:
        employees.push({numero: 7, prenom: "Erica", nomDeFamille: "Bélanger", salaireAnnuel: 999999999, dateEmbauche: "05/09/12"});
    }
```